# How can we pipe oracle password to background running sqlplus process on windows/Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, oracle

I have a requirement like, i need to execute one of the long running sql script say test.sql in background on Linux and Windows plaforms.

But if i execute test.sql like -

```
nohup sqlplus apps/<apps_pwd> @ test.sql &
```

Then output of ps -eaf command is leaking the apps password, which we passed on command line. On Unix, i can think of named pipes to pipe the password to background running process as -

```
cat pipe | nohup sqlplus apps @ test.sql &
```

But on Windows, there is no straight forward way to implement named pipes.

So, is there any other way of passing/piping oracle password to the background running sqlplus process? so that ps -eaf should not leak the passwords on the console.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle Wallet to store the password. See this [tutorial.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/twp-db-security-secure-ext-pwd-stor-133399.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems for my product, using oracle wallet is not feasible at this time.

Answer (score -2):

`echo ${PSWD} | sqlplus -s ${USERNAME}@SID @test.sql`

Comment: Sorry - `${USERNAME}` should be `${USERNAME}@SID`